# How to explain ":%g/<h[12]>/ t$" in vim?

Tags: regex, shell, vim

I found this

```
:%g/<h[12]>/ t$
```

in http://www.vimregex.com/

It says

> This command searches our file for the lines starting with `<h1>` or
>   `<h2>` and copies them to the end of the file.

but I can't understand the part `/ t$`, what's meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run this `help` command in `vim`:

```
:help copy
```

It will show following help that would explain everything:

```
:[range]co[py] {address}                *:co* *:copy*
            Copy the lines given by [range] to below the line
            given by {address}.

                            *:t*
:t          Synonym for copy.
```

**Full details:**

- `:g`: Global search
- `<h[12]>`: Search for `<h1>` or `<h2>`
- `t$` or `copy$`: Copy the lines given by `[range]` to below the line given by `{address}`.

You could make it more verbose. but more readable by using this equivalent command:

```
:%g/<h[12]>/ copy$
```

or this:

```
:%g/<h[12]>/ co$
```

To copy matching lines at the file start use:

```
:%g/<h[12]>/ copy0
```

Answer (score 2):

The `%` is the range of lines to run the command on -- `%` is the entire file.

The `g` command is "global" -- searches for lines that match a regex and applies another command to the matching lines

The `/<h[12]>/` is the regex to match.

The `t` command is "copy" -- copies the selected line(s) somewhere.  `$` is end, so the lines are copied to the end of the file.